# Loop for multiple star rating in 1 page

Tags: javascript, html

im having some issues with my star rating on a webpage.
i have a foreach loop where product details and a star rating are displayed for each product in my list.
However, now i am having the following issues:

1. when i first select the stars on the first product, all is good
2. when i click on the stars for the next product, it affects the rating for the first one

any help would be good!

This is part of the html

```
@foreach (var purchase in purchaseHistories)
                    {
                                        <div class="card rounded-3 mb-4">
                                          <div class="card-body p-4">
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                              <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                                                <img src="@purchase.ImageUrl" alt="@purchase.Name" class="img-fluid rounded-3" >
                                              </div>
                                              
                                              
                                              <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                                        <p class="lead fw-normal mb-2">@purchase.Name</p>
                                                        <p><span class="text-muted">@purchase.Description</span></p>
                                                        <p><span class="text-muted">Purchased On: @purchase.PurchaseDate</span></p>
                                                        <p><span class="text-muted">Quantity: @purchase.Quantity</span></p>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
                                              </div>
                                              
                                              

                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex flex-column">

                                            <div class="star-rating-container"  >
                                                <label for="star">Review:</label>
                                                <div>
                                                <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
                                                <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
                                                <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
                                                <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
                                                <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        
                                        






                                                <label for="Activation Code">Activation Code: </label>
                                                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Activation Code">

                                                @{
                                                    var split = purchase.ActivationCode.Split(",");
                                                    var val = 0;
                                                }
                                                
                                                @for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    if (i == 0)
                                                    {
                                                        <option selected>@split[i]</option>
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        val += 1;
                                                        <option value="@val">@split[i]</option>
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        

                                    </div>
```

this is part of the javascript

```
const products=document.querySelectorAll('.product')



    const allstars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
allstars.forEach((star, i) => {
    star.onclick = function () {
        let currentstar = i + 1;
        console.log(currentstar);

        allstars.forEach((star, j) => {
            if (currentstar >= j + 1) {
                star.innerHTML = '&#9733';
            } else {
                star.innerHTML = '&#9734';
            }
        })

    }
})
```

i tried adding another class to the star rating container but it doesnt seem to work..i dont know  how to adjust this so that the id for each star rating container for each purchase can be individually contained

Comment: The problem is that you are making a loop over all the the stars at the page, instead of a subset related to individual product. Please provide raw HTML to get the full answer =)

Comment: Edit your question to include a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your Javascript is selecting ALL elements with the star classes, so I suggest you try using (generated) IDs instead of classes to select them. Because all your buttons have the same class names, the code is looping over every single one of them and updating them.

Comment: Thanks @DavidNyan10! Yes, im slightly unsure how i can generate the IDs for each set of buttons as each product displayed will have its own set of buttons. But the number of products displayed will change depending on the data in the database..

Answer (score 1):

This type of elements do not require JS at all these days. Everything can be done with modern CSS and old good radios. Collect the radios in one `flex-direction: row-reverse` container with those radios aligned in reverse order, add a decoration element if needed and rely on some sort of a `input:checked ~ .deco` selector.
Here's a codepen example:
https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/VwEjRoP

But lets fix your code aswell. With a click you dont need to loop over all the stars at the page. Just loop over previous elements:

```js
star.onclick = function () {

    let prev = this;
    while( prev ){
        prev.innerHTML = '&#9733;';
        prev = prev.previousElementSibling;
    }

    // Also need to reset all the following
    let next = this.nextElementSibling;
    while( next ){
        next.innerHTML = '&#9734;';
        next = next.previousElementSibling;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared for your advice! Just to check, if i want to save the star rating in my database, would i still not need to use JS? I have some json/ajax code written for this function already but would this then be redundant?

Comment: Since you need to send the data with ajax, you will have to modify your JS code to collect the values from the radios. This is pretty trivial though.

Comment: Np. Consider to accept the answer that helped you move forward =)

Comment: @FZs once you set the `opacity` to zero for the inputs, they will become unclickable coz spans will overlap them. Spans and inputs have the same size and take the same space, so there's no difference around pixel hunting there.

Comment: I tried both ways, and it seemed to me like that, but now I see there's no difference. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define class `.stars` as a parent of `.star` and loop over the `.stars` to get the rating function works.

```js
const allstars = document.querySelectorAll('.stars');
allstars.forEach((stars) => {
  [...stars.children].forEach((star, i) => {
    star.onclick = function () {
      let currentstar = i + 1;
      [...stars.children].forEach((star, j) => {
          if (currentstar >= j + 1) {
              star.innerHTML = '&#9733;';
          } else {
              star.innerHTML = '&#9734;';
          }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="star-rating-container">
    <label for="star">Review 1:</label>
    <div class="stars">
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="star-rating-container">
    <label for="star">Review 2:</label>
    <div class="stars">
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="star-rating-container">
    <label for="star">Review 3:</label>
    <div class="stars">
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
      <button class="star" type="button">&#9734;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jordy for your help! I managed to add a for loop also to loop through the # of purchases shown dynamically. thank you so much :)